# Composite a 3D object into a photograph

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes

I was wondering how you would go about putting a 3D object into a photograph so that portions of the image are:

1. In front of, or
2. Behind the model.

For example, a photo taken from the roadside with a tree in the foreground.  I want to show a 3D model of a car in the photo on the road but a section of it is not visible because it is obscured by the tree.

Is this possible? If so, how can you do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try out the camera mapping techniques:
http://www.blenderguru.com/videos/camera-mapping-tutorial-v2/

Comment: two posts that will interest you: [cycles holdout material](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/565/47) and [cast shadows on footage/stills](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/518/how-to-make-a-model-cast-shadows-onto-the-world-texture-background)

Comment: while the answer to the question here is contained in both those links, I don't feel this question is a direct duplicate. It manages to ask a very succinct question and therefore is a good example of how to ask this question.

Comment: The most important part is covered by Jozsef but I would suggest you to dig a little in to **image based lightning**. You can do it with a regural **mirror ball**. It helps a lot in compositing CGI into footage - especialy that car ... is reflective:)

Answer (score 8):

To bring some sort of closure to this question *(as it's sure to get asked in the near future again)*, to get shadows and add a bit more realism, you can refer to the answer on [How to make a model cast shadows onto the world texture/background?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/518/how-to-make-a-model-cast-shadows-onto-the-world-texture-background).

**To answer this question with the one thing not mentioned there**. You don't really need to use compositing here as you might have thought, the simplest way to do this is to model an object to mimic the shape of the **object** you want to use to obscure your other object(s) *and while some people have and or will use some complex node setups*, you can just add a new material to the 'mask object', enable *Transparency*, set it to *Mask* and turn the *Alpha* to `0` like this..

[image]

Here is the setup of my scene, the tree trunk has the 'mask' material applied to it and I have a ground plane to catch a little shadow to make it a bit more realistic.. *I grabbed the picture of the tree from [here](http://www.mayang.com/textures/Plants/images/Trees/single_tree_1010258.JPG).*

[image]

and here it is rendered..

[image]

How to get it to look better is up to you and what you want..

Comment: Is there a quick way to do this in cycles?