# how to put a tracked model behind a person

Tags: animation

I have a video and a person walks in front of where I want to put the tracked model and I didn't know if you could cut him out so the model will go behind him like in AE or if that wasn't possible in blender.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create invisibility cloak (alpha mask material)](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7613/create-invisibility-cloak-alpha-mask-material)

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1103/composite-a-3d-object-into-a-photograph

Comment: Neither of those will help. This needs to be done with rotoscoping, it would be too complex to do it in any other way.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible, since blender has [fully featured masking capabilities](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.64/Mask_Editor).
Here is a simple setup to show you how it works:

[image]

If you were able to shoot against a green screen, use this setup instead:

[image]

Note: If you need to feather a certain point on you mask, you can hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>. If you need to feather the whole mask, add a color ramp node after the mask node, you can then tweak the feathering.

Comment: Just one comment. The way those things are done is using chroma keying in your video, otherwise masking has to be done manually and frame by frame.

Comment: @YoMismo, good point I'll add that!

Comment: This answer is good for proffesionals but a bigginer this hint is very short.

Comment: @Krishan I'm sorry but our site format does not support full tutorials. If you need more in depth instruction or step by step guidance, go to youtube to learn a little more about video masking in blender. Some search words i'd recommend are "Video Masking", "Blender Green-screen"  Or "Video tracking in blender". thanks --