# how can I make a 3D object appear behind an object in a video

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, video-sequence-editor, video

I'm considering making a VFX video with Blender and I want a 3D mesh in Blender to render partly behind a wall in the 2D video footage.

[image: Example]

How can I do this?

Comment: I'm no expert at VFX in Blender, but I would do this (after tracking the footage) by modeling the wall as accurately as possible in Blender and giving it a holdout shader.

Comment: What are you trying to do??? don't understand the question ... ok ... hmmm you want to ... a 3d mesh to be rendered behind a wall ... in the 2D video footage. Which means your wall is semi transparent so you could see the 3d mesh? I assume 2D video is the backplate you want your 3d objects to composite on top of your 2D video plate??

Comment: I don't see how this is unclear.  The OP wants to add CG objects to 2D live action footage, going behind walls and other objects etc.

Comment: Please place an image to clarify you question.  You are encouraging people to guess which in this case is not good.  How high quality do you want your product to be?

Comment: How can I add a photo I am browsing though a mobile phone and I see no option for that

Comment: Beware, you shouldn't use plain linked Video Tutorials like "[Track Match Blend](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLtuvwW4VAp5tu2RdbRHThM6FVFfvFur1g)"... It's better not to have help here than a link-only answer.

Comment: I don't still know how to insert a photo to clarify my question

Comment: This is the link for the photo I want to post:
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/8XOr8yec-ds/maxresdefault.jpg

Comment: I included the picture for you - it's a great help to show what you meant. Just look at your questions Markdown Code now to see how this [works](http://blender.stackexchange.com/editing-help#images).

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1103/2843

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7613/create-invisibility-cloak-alpha-mask-material, http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15450/2843, http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/24410/2843, http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5131/using-mask-as-a-garbage-matte-to-hide-an-object, http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/23865/2843, http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/14169/2843

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7613/2843, http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/33301/2843

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5104/2843

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to put a tracked model behind a person](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14167/how-to-put-a-tracked-model-behind-a-person)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can do this, off the top of my head:

1: MASKING - you can setup a simple box mask to remove/hide the part of the 3D object so that it appears to be "hidden" partially behind the wall in the video even though it is a layer sitting on top of the video.

2: PROJECTION MAPPING - this way is more complicated. You recreate the video scene in the 3D viewport, apply the video as textures to each object, set lighting, then position your 3D object and animate as necessary. This gives more accurate results in terms of shadows from the 3D animated object moving within the actual/recreated scene.

Depending on the end result that you're looking for, these are just a couple of ways to get there.