# Motion Tracking for Still Image

Tags: compositing-nodes, tracking

I'm well aware of motion tracking, being able to put three-dimesional objects in video (or video effects/CGI) but what if I want to put it in a single image? I tried doing motion tracking with my still image but, it didn't work. All I want to do is make it look like there's text in the scene. BTW I'm using Cycles (but I'm okay if it works better in blender-internal.)

I tried adding a reference image, but I can't seem to get the rotation and location right of the object, it doesn't look like it's part of the picture. 
So how do I get the object to look like it's part of the scene?

Here's the image I'm trying to add text to: 
(it's to large to upload) 

https://www.pexels.com/photo/green-grass-field-113723/

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1103/599

Comment: *Motion* tracking for a *Still* image is a bit of an oxymoron.  You just mean placing a 3D model in a still image right?

Comment: @PGmath exactly yes. Just using a reference image doesn't seem to convey the realism...

Comment: @gandalf3 Whilst that question is very useful to me(thank you) I want more of a solid way to make the object(text) seem like it's part of the picture, like finding the right distance from the camera, by like using the camera focal length, idk.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33625/still-frame-camera-solve/33628#33628 and: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40308/how-do-i-align-my-grid-to-background-footage/40330#40330

Answer (score 3):

**Motion tracking will not work on a still image** you need some difference in a sequence of images called parallax for blender to re-create 3D information. For still images you have a couple of choices:

- 1- Use the image you want to match as a [background image](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/67861/1853) and then try to match the perspective manually. Set the viewport to camera view <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>, then **lock camera to view** and position the camera. The grid may be very helpful to visualize the ground should be.

[image]

The tricky part here is trying to match the lens used for the original image.

For more details read: [How do I align my grid to background footage?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40308/how-do-i-align-my-grid-to-background-footage/40330#40330)

- 2- Use an addon like [Blam](https://github.com/stuffmatic/blam).

From the Blam users manual:

> BLAM is a camera calibration add-on for Blender and is meant to facilitate modeling based on photos or synthetic images rendered with a perspective projection camera.

Blam uses the grease pencil to help you determine and match the perspective of an image and match a blender scene to it.

**UPDATE:** Blam is no longer mantained and has been replaced by fspy:

https://fspy.io/

**Read: [How can I recreate geometry using a photograph?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102697/how-can-i-recreate-geometry-using-a-photograph)**