# How do I add a background image as a camera lens?

Tags: camera, image

I'm tyring to render some images references for a comic book I am making. After posing my models and props, I will be trying to find the best angle and then I will render an image.

In order for me to create the page, I will be loading a panel template as a reference. This is basically a bunch of rectangles that give me a reference where my comic book panels on the page will be.

I will adjust my render dimensions (this changes camera view dimensions too) to have a comic book page height and width. I want to load the panel template as a background image (which has the same height and width) so that it is locked to the camera view.

This way, when I press the key *Zero*, I see what my camera sees. If I then select the checkbox *Lock Camera To View*, I can rotate around an object while seeing what the camera sees.

What I want to know is how do I get the panel template image locked to the camera view.

*This will give me the ability to find the best angle and zoom for my scene while adjusting it for the appropriate panel in the template.*

How do I do this?

*Thanks to the answer, here is snapshot of what I was trying to achieve:*

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this by adding a **Background Image**. To do this, go into the 3D Viewport and press the <kbd>N</kbd> key to open the panel on the right hand side. Scroll down to the very bottom, and you should see an option *Background Images*. Go ahead and enable it.

[image: background_image]

Now add an image and change the view from *All Views* to *Camera*.

[image: change_view]

Now in the camera view you will have a background image that transforms with the camera.

[image: final_result]

Comment: This does exactly what I want. Thank you!

Comment: Always happy to help

Comment: How to set different images for two cameras?

Comment: I'm not sure that's possible, I would just add multiple and toggle which one is visible. Maybe someone else has some ideas on how to do this. This could be another question potentially btw.

Comment: Works great except if you have an environment map enabled in which case the background image does not show up. With cycle engine, remedy to this problem by switching on the "transparent" checkbox under Render/Film

Answer (score 5):

In recent blender versions (e.g., 2.9X) this feature has moved to the right properties panes -> camera properties

[image]

Comment: Be careful with blender v.290. This feature has been removed or maybe is an addon https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6Vld.jpg