# Matching lens distortion in a still image composite?

Tags: camera, compositing-nodes, distort

Hi I'm a little stumped as to how match lens distortion in a still image composite... motion tracking gives you a lot of options but how do you go about it with still composites?

Comment: Do you have the used lens and camera at hand? Then you could capture a lens grid. If not: does the metadata of your image contain lens and sensor information? Then you could position by trial and error.

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/62096/37728

Comment: Yann - I do have the data from the camera. It's a DJI FC300S ... can you explain how to use a lens grid?

Comment: Dimali - I'm aware of the basics of matching focal length etc... but how do you match the distortion? What I have is a long straight bridge that needs to be bent to match the lens distortion... I don't want to actually bend the bridge as I have multiple images to place it in, I want the camera to distort it.