# Cycles masking object (blocking partial rendering of object)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, masking

I am slowly starting to get to grips with Blender basics, but i am currently stuck.

I made a very basic scene using a hdri backround. I would like to create a plane that would "block" the rendering of an object so that it will look like the object is moving around the corner of the building.

The image shows the effect I am trying to create. The sphere on the right needs to be partially hidden by a plane and the background rendered as if there was nothing in front of it.

[image]

I looked at this example :
[Create invisibility cloak (alpha mask material)](http://file:///C:/Users/Ninja/Desktop/Project/Blender/web/rendering%20-%20Create%20invisibility%20cloak%20(alpha%20mask%20material)%20-%20Blender%20Stack%20Exchange.html)
When I enable the Film->Transparent option the plain in front of the sphere does partially block the rendering of the sphere, but then I have no background.

hdri background :
[image]

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1103/composite-a-3d-object-into-a-photograph/1120#1120

Comment: This is the link I meant to put in the description :https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7613/create-invisibility-cloak-alpha-mask-material

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your link is broken so I can't see the method you're using.

You can continue like you are and render two images: one of the spheres with transparency on, one of just the background, and then composite them with the *Compositor*.  I don't believe you can use *Render Layers* here because the ***Tranparent*** option is not render-layer specific.

Or you can do what I did and use a cube to act as the building corner with the ***Boolean Modifier*** enabled:

[image]

[image]

Just make the corner cube invisible and set the following options:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you also have a modifier on the building corner cube ? I followed your instructions : set the BuildingCorner not visible and not rendered. Add the boolean modifier to the Pedestrain with difference to the building corner. But it renders just the Pedestrain cube then. What did I miss ?

Comment: Oh okay I understand what you where doing. The Pedestrian is subtracted where the two bodies overlap. The pedestrian moves into the Building corner more and more and less is render. Very good and clever idea. I thank you.

Comment: You got it!  You're very welcome.